# Data value for a powered lever?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How would I `/testforblock` if a lever is powered and is facing west (see the image).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Minecraft 1.13, this command no longer requires the use of cryptic numbers

```
/execute if block X Y Z minecraft:lever[facing=west,powered=true]
```

Answer (score 1):

The Damage value for a powered lever facing west is 10.

```
/testforblock X Y Z minecraft:lever 10
```

The wiki states data values [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Lever#Block_data).