# Minecraft Redstone Help

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I need help with a map, I'm wondering if there's a command to make a lever or a button to trigger a command block without the command block being behind the button or any redstone near the button.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: Sure, `testforblock`. But your question sounds like you don't know much about redstone, command blocks, commands, block states or anything you would need for this task. So I would recommend you to watch [a commands tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4ZS2guXqa_g1NI8t0djmrRtOaZ6brg46), the [wiki page about redstone circuits](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Redstone_circuit) and look up some example commands with block states. If you don't want to put that much effort into it, just put the lever on a wall and the command block directly behind it.

Comment: [Here is a question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/258555/186522) which deals with `testforblock` and testing a powered lever.

Comment: Archive for the second link in my comment#2: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/index.php?title=Redstone_circuit&oldid=1177961

Answer (score 1):

The best option is to have a repeating command block that is always active (or active when you want it to be) constantly checking for a pressed button, or in this case, a stone button with a certain damage value. That command block will lead into a conditional command block that will perform whatever action you want.

```
/testforblock ~x ~y ~z minecraft:stone_button [damage value]
 |
 | conditional
 |
 V
/tellraw @a {"text":"Successful"}
```

The `[damage value]` will change depending upon the direction of the button:

> East: 9
>
> West: 10
>
> South: 11
>
> North: 12

Play around with the command a bit and you should get it working ;)

---

source: [www.minecraftforum.net](https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-java-edition/redstone-discussion-and/349092-testforblock-pushed-buttons#c2)